# Tracert skips hops only see the end IP

Tags: dns, traceroute

When i use tracert for windows it will 'timeout' on all of the address' between my router and the target, the exact number of timeouts represent exactly to the hops it would normally take (i used my laptop to see if it was my router or something).

I have changed over to both preffered and alternate DNS as the public google ones with no change, what is going on?

http://puu.sh/ej44d/c7c6c206be.png
This is another program i used to test it out, similar result
http://puu.sh/ejh5R/be9260c537.png

Answer (score 0):

As security on the network has been steadily increasing, one easy thing that many people do now is to basically disable aspects of ICMP protocol.  This prevents responding to traceroutes and returning the FQDN from the hop.  Sometimes administrators lock things down do tight that even a ping does not work.

So there is nothing necessarily wrong here.

Comment: "Nothing necessarily wrong" except for the utterly wrong idea that blocking ICMP _error_ messages somehow improves network security...

Comment: A trend is that if you don't know who they are they can't directly be attacked.